# SQL Syntax error - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I created a method to build an SQL query on Rails, and I'm getting a syntax error, no idea why, the code looks correct to me.
Maybe someone here is able to find the issue? It's likely something pretty obvious that I'm not noticing.

My code:

```
def build_query(info_arr)
  <<~SQL
     SELECT * FROM word_group_values WHERE account_id = :account_id
       AND word_group_id <> :word_group_id
       AND ("title", location) IN #{info_arr.join(', ')}
  SQL
end
```

The error I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")" LINE 2: AND ("title", location) IN () ^ : SELECT * FROM word_group_values WHERE account_id = 110
 AND ("title", location) IN ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is

```
SELECT * FROM word_group_values WHERE account_id = 110  AND ("title", location) IN ()
```

Since `info_arr` is empty you are getting an empty string and this is an invalid query.

(`syntax error at or near ")` is complaining about the empty `()`)

You need to pass an array of tuples for it to be valid. A plain string will probably not work in this case, unless `info_arr` is that but is coming empty.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need SQL string but to filter records by two columns you can build SQL query by this principle:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1, column2) IN ((valu11, value21), (valu12, value22));
```

It means you need outer and inner brackets in your string

Don't forget to sanitize SQL query

```rb
def build_query(account_id:, word_group_id:, titles_locations_filters: [])
  base_query =
    ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql(
      [
        <<~SQL.squish,
          SELECT * FROM word_group_values
          WHERE account_id = :account_id
          AND word_group_id <> :word_group_id
        SQL
        account_id:, word_group_id:
      ]
    )

  return base_query if titles_locations_filters.empty?

  title_locations =
    titles_locations_filters.map do |title, location|
      ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql([
        '(:title, :location)', # inner brackets
        title:, location:
      ])
    end.join(', ')

  "#{base_query} AND (title, location) IN (#{title_locations})" # outer brackets
end
```

And call it such way

```rb
account_id = 100
word_group_id = 200
titles_locations_filters = [%w[title1 location1], %w[title2 location2]]

build_query(account_id:, word_group_id:)
# SELECT * FROM word_group_values
# WHERE account_id = 100
# AND word_group_id <> 200

build_query(account_id:, word_group_id:, titles_locations_filters:)
# SELECT * FROM word_group_values
# WHERE account_id = 100
# AND word_group_id <> 200
# AND (title, location) IN (('title1', 'location1'), ('title2', 'location2'))
```